# Optimizing memory and LOC used when all class instances return the same value

Tags: java, performance, memory

I have a case where all instances of subclasses should return the same value. 
Since there will be a lot of instances I want to reduce the amount of memory the use. 
I made the following experiment:

1) Using fields and implementing the methods once. (This implementation uses 24 bytes)

```
private abstract class A{

    private String string;
    private int i;

    public A(String string, int i) {
        this.string = string;
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return string;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return i;
    }

}

private class B extends A{


    public B() {
        super("B",10);
    }

}
```

2) Reimplementing methods for each class. (This implementation uses 16 bytes)

```
private abstract class A{

    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract int getAge();

}

private class B extends A{

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "B";
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return 10;
    }

}
```

I read the object size using VisualVm.
Does anyone see a way I could implement the methods only once while reducing the amount of memory used?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: 
Since my question got downvoted a few times please let me know how I can improve it.

Comment: Did you try making `A` an interface in your second example?

Comment: @Bernat this is just an example. In my really application A is a class providing some common methods.

Comment: About downvote: I don't see why it would be a bad question. I think people don't like micro-optimization :)

Comment: @Joel I know in general you should not do them, but sometimes they are needed.

Comment: yes, and you must also be aware that there's no guarantee that the gain is stable across different versions / implementations of the JVM.

Comment: @Joel thanks for the tip. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more subtle. In fact you want to have every child class to have its specific class (static) constant. A non-static method is used for that, as Java seems to offer no other means.

Though less neat-looking, the second solution seems more adequate. What is hard on my sense of nice code style.

> I propose collecting all constants in an immutable class, and use either method, the second being nicer, though needing a method.

However one could do it following both *intent* of using a class static constant,
and *optimal memory* resp. not copying same data in every field:

```
class MetaData {
    public final String string;
    public final int i;
    MetaData(String string, int i) {
        this.string = string;
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

Just one instance per child class. In fact one could consider not using child classes but a factory and delegation in class A.

```
private abstract class A {
    protected final MetaData metaData;

    public A(MetaData metaData) {
        this.metaData = metaData;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return metaData.string;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return metaData.i;
    }

    public MetaData getMetaData() {
        return metaData;
    }
}

private class B extends A {

    private static final MetaData b = new MetaData("B", 10);
    public B() {
        super(b);
    }
}
```

Of course instead of constructor+super field, one could better make

```
    protected abstract MetaData getMetaData();

    @Override
    protected MetaData getMetaData() {
        return b;
    }
```

The advantage would be when later an extra constant has to be added in the hierarchy.

Comment: I wonder if having `protected final MetaData metaData;` in the abstract layer is not going to add some bytes overhead. In terms of memory it's almost identical to OP first example, with an additional class.

Comment: @Joel, I was still editing and the same technique of an abstract method is usable for constant container too. You are right, an int spared only.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you for your solution. 
This basically makes every subclass instance in the example 16 bytes + 24 bytes per subclass for the metadata package. That is a very nice solution.